# Android spinner does not open

Tags: android

I added a spinner to my app, and it's not showing up.
the spinner is in a different XML file of the activity, defined in a viewHolder for a RecyclerView.
My code is:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ImageButton btnAdd;
    GoogleSignUpAdapter googleSignUpAdapter;
    public ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterGender;
    public ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterDistance;
    public  Spinner avgDistance,gender,maxDistance;
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_sign_up);
        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.LVG_Add);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        googleSignUpAdapter=new GoogleSignUpAdapter();

        recyclerView.setAdapter(googleSignUpAdapter);

        btnAdd= findViewById(R.id.BtnAdd);
        //GoogleSignUpViewHolder.setGender(recyclerView);
        LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        gender= (Spinner) inflater.inflate(R.layout.gender_item,null).findViewById(R.id.GenderSpiner);
        avgDistance= (Spinner)inflater.inflate(R.layout.avg_distance_item,null).findViewById(R.id.AvgDistanceSpiner);
        maxDistance= (Spinner)inflater.inflate(R.layout.max_distance_item,null).findViewById(R.id.MaxDistanceSpinner);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        adapterGender = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.gender_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapterDistance = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.avg_distance_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapterGender.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_item);
       adapterDistance.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


        gender.setAdapter(adapterGender);
        avgDistance.setAdapter(adapterDistance);
        maxDistance.setAdapter(adapterDistance);

    }
```

the XML of the Spinner is:

````
        android:id="@+id/GenderSpiner"
        android:background="@drawable/boxtext"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"

        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" /> ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I suggest switching from `spinner` to `TextInputLayout`. There is a way to implement an exposed dropdown menu.

Scroll down to the section `Implementing an exposed dropdown menu`

[Text fields](https://material.io/components/text-fields/android#using-text-fields)

Comment: I didn't succeed, another idea?